# Batch file to call all other batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I create a "do everything" batch file that simply calls **all** other batch files in its directory and executes them one after the other?

My attempts using

```
for /r %%i in (*.bat) do call %%i
```

Fail miserably, because obviously the file will sooner or later call itself and end up in an endless loop of calling itself time and time again.

How can I manage this better?

Comment: You can retrieve the filename from the 'main' file using `%~nx0`. Perhaps you could use this in an if within the forloop to skip the 'main' file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

rename your starting bat file as `.CMD`

or

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*.bat) do if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" call %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an if statement inside your for loop:

```
for /r %%i in (*.bat) do (if "%~dpnx0" NEQ "%%~i" call "%%i")
```